# Python customtkinter CTkButton being a black square before displaying style

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I basically have 4 (the problem is the same with a single button too) CTkButton widget.

When I place them using `.place`, they take a split second to actually show the style I've given them, and prior to that, it's just a black square. Is this one of customtkinter/tkinter's limitations or what?
Take a look at what I'm saying:
[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkzrf.gif)
Thanks in advance.